# How to debug (like gdb) with radare2?

Tags: radare2, debuggers

I am new to radare2 and Linux. I got problem with `r2`.

As the title states it, many tutorials, articles, videos about `r2` are just about disassembling programs, and read assembly codes. But, I want debug my programs.

I search on the web and on GitHub... But did not find anything meaningful (or maybe I did miss it).

I would like to know if somebody could tell me how to run the debugger in `r2`.

Comment: you need to be a bit more specific about what exactly you want to do, otherwise this question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to archives of [hack.lu](http://hack.lu) conference [here](http://archive.hack.lu/2015/).

You can find there Radare2 [workshop](http://archive.hack.lu/2015/radare2-workshop-slides.pdf) [materials](http://archive.hack.lu/2015/radare2-workshop/).
There are some mentions of debugging there.

In addition you have a radare 2 book, see [basic debugging session](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/first_steps/basic_debugger_session.html) chapter.
I'd suggest to read all the book and workshop materials.

Comment: thanks, im so noob, just add -d as parameter, r2 will run in debug mode.

I have one more problem: can u guide me use [radeco](https://github.com/radare/radeco) and add it to r2?

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't decompile yet, it just creates dependency graphs. Use retdec plugin, you can install it with r2pm.

Comment: radare2 book has moved [here](https://book.rada.re/first_steps/basic_debugger_session.html)